# Gparted: What does it mean when a partition is labeled as Image?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk-image

I wish to merge two partitions to increase the size of `/` on my laptop. This is what I see on Gparted

[image]

/dev/sda5 is labeled as Image. I am not sure whether this implies VirtualBox image. But if it does, I wish to reallocate it to `ext4` ie. `/`.

Please tell me if it is safe to format `/dev/sda5` labeled image too `ext4`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dev/sda5` is the Windows Recovery Image that your manufacturer places on your laptop so you can restore Windows to its factory state if something goes wrong in Windows. `dev/sda4`(Windows Recovery Tools) work hand in hand with `dev/sda5`(the manufacturer factory image). If you use Windows and Linux(dual boot), *please don't touch it, move it, rename it, edit it, etc*. So, you can't delete it if you dual boot.

If however, you plan to only use Ubuntu(and *only* Ubuntu/Linux), then there is no need for the partition.

Comment: Could you point me to a link or elaborate how I could save the image on a flash drive and merge that space with `dev/sda6` where `/` is?

Comment: To add to Tony's answer, `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5` can be used to restore your hard disk to the way it was the first day you had the computer.  This is useful for lots of things: restoring Windows if you sell or give the computer away, reversing virus damage of the Windows partition, etc.  My advice would be to not touch those two partitions unless you really know what you're doing and you're really sure you never want the computer to ever run Windows again.

Comment: @VineetKaushik Some manufacturers have recovery images on their websites, so you just need to google your manufacturer's name with "recovery image", and they might have an ISO that you can make as a USB. Just make sure the ISO is exactly for your model, and be ready to install drivers, etc. *But*, only do this if you are *very* confident in what you want to do. My suggestion is to free 3GB from `dev/sda3` and add it to the `dev/sda6` partition, that is, your Ubuntu partition.